# Bottle POST or PUT requests don't see more than one parameter

Tags: python, rest, curl, bottle

I'm trying to pass several parameters using POST or PUT, but I'm getting only first

```
@route('/command/', method='PUT')
def execute(command="Unknown"):
    param1 = request.query.get("param1")
    param2 = request.query.get("param2")
    param3 = request.query.get("param3")
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(command, param1, param2, param3))
    return "Executed {} {} {} {}".format(command, param1, param2, param3)
```

using the request like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://host:port/mycommand/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

Bottle logs: `"PUT /command/?param1=value1 HTTP/1.1"`
and param2 and param3 are printed out as "None", like they are cut off on the `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *put quotes around the URL*:

```
curl -X PUT "http://host:port/mycommand/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3"
```

Comment: that just means that i have to stop and go home right now;) -d variant didn't work but quotes helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneSajine exactly, I've removed that `-d` option to avoid confusion. Thanks for the tests.